# Using file handling read integers from file and display data in array

Tags: c

```
# include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int a[10], n, i;
    char file_name[20];

    printf("enter the file name \n");
    scanf("%s", file_name);
    printf("enter number of integers \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error in opening file \n");
        return;
    }
    fread(a, 1, n, fp);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d \n", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

enter the file name       /home/n/t1.txt      enter number of integers 
3     1540736144      1540736144      1540736144..

In file t1.txt , i have entered the intergers {10,20,30,40.50}
and stored in path /home/n/t1.txt..

But in output it is displaying some junk addresses..
Kindly guide me how to display the integers stored in file..

Comment: Judging by the file name's extension, your file seems to be a text file, but you are reading binary data with `fread`. You want `fscanf` or a combination of `fgets` and `sscanf` or `strtok`plus `strtol`.

Comment: Also, you're not checking for errors in most of your library calls.

Comment: Also `fread(a, 1, n, fp);` --> `fread(a, sizeof(int), n, fp);`

Answer (score 1):

Your file is a text file, which is human-readabla and can be edited in text editors. You treat it like a binary file, which stores data in the same way it is stored in the memory. Such files are compact and fast to read, but not easily editable or readable by humans.

The C standard provides different functions to deal with these file types. `fwrite` and `fread` are for binary files. `fprintf`, `fscanf`, `fgets` and so on are for text files.

There are several ways to parse your input and SO is full of examples. A cheap way to read data is `fscanf`. It ignores new-lines and just treats them as white space. It is not a good way to read input if you have more complex data or if you need good eror handling, but for your small example, it will do. Your input doesn't seem to be organised in lines.

The code below defines the function `scan_int`, which reads a number of integers from a file. The `main` function shows how to use this function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 *      Read at most max integers from a file and store them in arr.
 *      Return the number of integers read or -1 on file access error.
 *      Numbers may or may not be separated with commas.
 */
int scan_int(const char *fn, int arr[], int max)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(fn, "r");
    int n = 0;

    if (f == NULL) return -1;

    while (n < max && fscanf(f, "%d,", &arr[n]) == 1) n++;
    fclose(f);

    return n;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[10];
    int i, n;

    n = scan_int("data.txt", a, 10);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i) printf(", ");
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you valuable input.. But in the above code you are not using fread.. function..

Comment: Yes, because `fread` is not the function to use here. It's a bit like saying "Thanks for fastening that screw, but you didn't use the hammer."